# Reading text file into dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

my text file has a format:

```
car,coche,auto
chair,silla,stuhl,sella
```

The first element is the english word. I want to create a dictionary that does the following and returns dictionary.

```
dict =        {'coche'  : 'car',
               'auto'   : 'car',
               'stilla' : 'chair',
               'stuhl'  : 'chair',
               'sella'  : 'chair' }
```

I cannot use any built in function just loops and basic functions.

I know I want to:

- split the elements of each line
- set the first item as the key
- assign the second item as a value
- assign the following values to the same key

```
    open_file = open(words_file_name, 'r')
    conversions = {}
    for line in open_file:
        piece = open_file.split(',')
        key = piece[0]
        conversions[key] = 0 
        if piece not in conversions:
            conversions[piece] = 1
        conversions[piece] += 1
    for key, value in conversions:
        return conversions
```

I have continuously gotten key errors, etc.

Comment: `piece = open_file.split(',')` should be `piece = line.split(',')` and why are you doing `key = piece[0]` when this will be the value for each subsequent word? `piece` will be a list like `['car', 'coche', 'auto']` after  and `piece[0]` will be `'car'`

Comment: I was attempting to assign the first item of the list as the key value but now I see it is backwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested but should work I think. Pop the first item, and use it as a value for all other words.

```
d = {}
with open('your-file.txt', 'r') as fhin:
    for line in fhin:
        words = line.strip().split(',')
        en_word = words.pop(0)
        for word in words:
            d[word] = en_word
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very close. It just seems that you have key and value backwards. The dictionary you are trying to create has the English word as the value and the non-English words as the keys of the dictionary.

```
open_file = open(words_file_name, 'r')
conversions = {}
for line in open_file:
    piece = line.split(',')
    value = piece[0]               # <- the first item will be the value
    for key in piece[1:]:          # <- iterate over the rest of the items in the line
        conversions[key] = value   # <- add the key:value pair to the dictionary
print(conversions)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this using `dict.fromkeys`

```
open_file = open(words_file_name, 'r')
conversions = {}
for line in open_file:
    val, keys = line.strip().split(',', 1)
    conversions.update(dict.fromkeys(keys.split(','), val))

print (conversions)
```

**Output**

```
{'sella': 'chair', 'coche': 'car', 'stuhl': 'chair', 'silla': 'chair', 'auto': 'car'}
```

Comment: We have only learned and can only use get, clear, items, keys, pop, popitem, and values. the emphasis is using loops and key elements. for example                     for line in words_file:
    c = line.strip('\n').split(' ')
    if c[2] not in parties:
        parties[c[2]] = 0
    counts[c[2]] += 1

Answer (score 0):

simple loops:

```
open_file = open('read.txt', 'r')
conversions = {}
for line in open_file:
    piece = line.rstrip().split(',') #rstrip to remove \n
    key = piece[0]
    for obj in piece[1:]:
        conversions[obj]=key
print (conversions)
```

Output :

```
{'sella': 'chair', 'coche': 'car', 'stuhl': 'chair', 'silla': 'chair', 'auto': 'car'}
```

Answer (score -1):

it looks like you have a csv. You should try using `csv.DictReader()` from the csv module

```
import csv
csv_data=csv.DictReader(open('file_loc'))
for row in csv_data:
    #DoSomething
```

this will make csv_data an `OrderedDict`, you can typecast it to Dict using `dict(object)`

Comment: Cant use that function